# Escaping HTTP Headers

Tags: java, http-headers, escaping

I was wondering if there is a Java library that contains a method to escape HTTP header attributes? I'd like to prevent injections and I was wondering if something already exists instead of trying to roll my own.

Comment: What sort of escaping? Can you provide an example of what you want to prevent?

Comment: All of them, ideally. A good example is cache poisoning. You can see some examples [here](http://ha.ckers.org/response-splitting.html).